# Change the teams of some users

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary that keeps a team name (**string**) and the users of the team (**list**). I want to change the teams of some users.

My idea is to find the **place** of the user who we want to move and **remove** it from the current collection. Then **add** the user to the **desired team**. The problem is I can't find the given user place in the dictionary, thus I am not able to solve it.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

dictionary.Add("Lighter", new List<string>() { "Royal", "JSmith" });
dictionary.Add("Darker", new List<string>() { "DCay", "Rebecca" });

string userToMove = "DCay";
string whereToMove = "Lighter";;
// expected results: 
// Lighter: Royal, JSmith, DCay
// Darker: Rebecca
```

I did the best I could for this post and I hope it is better than my old ones.

Answer (score 3):

Full code with my comments:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

dictionary.Add("Lighter", new List<string>() { "Royal", "JSmith" });
dictionary.Add("Darker", new List<string>() { "DCay", "Rebecca" });

string userToMove = "DCay";
string whereToMove = "Lighter";

var list = dictionary.Values.SingleOrDefault(l => l.Contains(userToMove));  // list with user name
list?.Remove(userToMove);  // remove user from current list if user in list
dictionary[whereToMove].Add(userToMove); // add user to new list
```